# Assigning a value based on button click event

Tags: javascript

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;
     
$('#showbtn').click(function (){
  hasBeenClicked = true;
});
if (hasBeenClicked==true) {
  var input = 10; 
}
else {
  var input = 20;
}
localStorage.setItem("score",input);
```

The score is shown as 20 for both cases, that is even if the button is pressed the value won't change. If the button is pressed then the value should be changed to 10.

Comment: Do you want all the code to run on button click, because it currently only sets hasBeenClicked to true.

Comment: You declare `input` twice inside if/else statement, and you are trying to use it outside that scope.

Comment: FYI you should write `if (hasBeenClicked==true)` as `if (hasBeenClicked)`.

Comment: I'd suggest using a var input outside the scope with a default value of 20 and change it inside the function so when you store it you get the 10 or 20 you're looking for.
`
var input = 20;
     
$('#showbtn').click(function (){
    input = 10;
});
localStorage.setItem("score", input);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `localStorage.setItem` is running before you can click the button so input will always be `20`, to set the score to 10 if it has been clicked you need to reset it in your onClick. Also no need for the if statements anymore

```js
localStorage.setItem("score",20);

$('#showbtn').click(function (){
  localStorage.setItem("score",10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

/* Pleas Try this, the var input is out of scope, the if else statement will 10 if the button is clicked if not it will save 20 */

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;
     
$('#showbtn').click(function (){
  hasBeenClicked = true;
});
if (hasBeenClicked==true) {
  var input = 10; 
localStorage.setItem("score",input);
}
else {
  var input = 20;
localStorage.setItem("score",input);
}
```